# jquery on('load', ...) is not getting called

Tags: jquery

If I put an iframe in the html body my 'on load' is called.
But when I append an iframe to the body it does not get called.
Why is that and what can be done about that?

```
$('iframe').on('load', function() {
    console.log("loading iframe");
});

$body.append('<iframe id="frame" src="http://lalalala.nl/index_of/content?F=2"></iframe>');
```

Comment: If you append it after setting event, it won't be called

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan That's not right as i understand your previous comment.   https://jsfiddle.net/crLxp6j5/  What needs OP i guess is to delegate load event. But as this event doesn't bubble, he could set inline onload attribute or capture it: http://jsfiddle.net/2u56bqno/

Comment: @A.Wolff ok, my bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the iframe doesn't yet exist when you call `$('iframe')`, so you're not binding to any elements. Reverse the order of the operations.

```
$body.append('<iframe id="frame" src="http://lalalala.nl/index_of/content?F=2"></iframe>');
$('iframe').on('load', function() {
    console.log("loading iframe");
});
```

Or you can create the iframe as a disconnected element and bind it, then append it.

```
$('<iframe id="frame" src="http://lalalala.nl/index_of/content?F=2"></iframe>').on('load', function() {
    console.log("loading iframe");
}).appendTo($body);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the iframe element first and then appending it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var iframe = $('<iframe id="frame" "src="..." />').on('load', function(){
    alert('loaded');
  });

  $('body').append($(iframe)); 
});
```